# AB test for specific time duration during a day daily

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize

Is it possible to run ab test for specific time daily,

eg. if i want to run ab test during day time only daily how can i do it?

case
test will run during 9:00am to 9:00pm US timezone daily

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is it possible to run ab test for specific time daily.

Example: Target visitors browsing your site in the morning
You want to target experiments to users visiting your site during the morning hours. To do this, write a JavaScript function that returns the current hour (with possible values 0-23). Then, create a targeting condition that looks for a returned value that is less than 12.

Step 1: Create a custom variable
Create or edit an experiment.
Click the TARGETING tab.
Click AND to add a new targeting rule.
Click Custom JavaScript.
Click Variable, then Create new...
Optionally, click an existing variable to edit it.
Enter your Custom JavaScript in the open text field (see a sample below).
Name your variable – for example, Browser time.
Click CREATE VARIABLE.
Sample JavaScript which returns the time that the browser’s clock is set to:

```
function() {
  return (new Date()).getHours();
}
```

Step 2: Build a condition with your custom variable
After creating your custom variable, Optimize will populate it in a new targeting condition which you can complete by adding a match type and value. For this example, build a targeting condition that looks for a returned value of 11 or less and click SAVE.

| Variable | Match type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Browser time | less than | 12 |

This condition will evaluate true if:

the value of the Browser time variable is less than 12.
This condition will evaluate false if:

the value of the Browser time variable is 12 or greater.

Refecences:
https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6301785?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: Seems good, will try it. Thanks